# XCode insists on using a revoked certificate

Tags: swift, macos

```
ERROR ITMS-90721: "Certificate Revoked. The signing certificate "C=GB, O=XXX, OU=Y, CN=3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: NAME (XXX), UID=XXX” with serial number 123456789 used to sign APP.pkg has been revoked. Learn more (https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09)."
```

I've tried repeatedly (including actually revoking all certificates in the Developer portal and re-issuing), cleaning the build folder, restarting XCode/OSX .

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: check your developer account on apples dev site. looks like you need a new certificate

Comment: I already have the correct certificates, but XCode seems to insist on using an old, revoked one.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this issue related on old Revoked Certificates that located in your project. Follow to go this path in XCode:

`XCode -> Preferences.. -> Accounts -> Manage Certificates`

Try to remove all old and revoked certificates in that window. I had the similar issue and it's help for me.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't work there is no option to delete the certificates as they are not showing as revoked and as if they are in the keychain (even though they are not).. It feels as if there is a bug in the API... So frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of additional things to try :

1. In the keychain app, remove the revoked certificate
2. In Xcode -> Preferences -> Account, delete your account and re-add it.

That should ensure Xcode downloads a current certificate.